# Py2exe created executable works at first then stops working

Tags: python, py2exe

I wrote a script that creates 50 boxes of random color.  The script works normally, but once I used py2exe to make it an executable file, it stopped working. The executable worked at first, but then later it stopped working. I started getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named turtle
```

Here is my python code:

```
import turtle
from random import randint
colors = ['red', 'green', 'yellow', 'purple', 'blue', 'orange', 'black', 'lightgreen',   'navyblue', 'pink']
window = turtle.Screen()
box = turtle.Turtle()
box.speed(4)
box.penup()
box.setx(-350)
box.sety(200)
box.pendown()
for num in range(100):
    box.color(colors[randint(0, 9)])
    for x in range(4):
        box.forward(30)
        box.left(90)
    x = box.xcor()
    if x >= 350:
        y = box.ycor() - 60
        x = box.xcor() - 700
    else:
        y = box.ycor()
        x = box.xcor() + 45

    box.goto(x, y)
```

I really am not sure why it started giving me this error.

My .exe file is to long to post here, and it is incomprehensible to me anyway.
I have python 27's tkinter, so I don't think that's the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Is that the exact error message? The capitalization looks off.

Comment: I changed the capitalization of the error message.

Comment: If it worked before, but doesn't now, you must've changed something in setup.py, or added a new dependency.  Try deleting your build directories and recompiling, post the output of `python setup.py py2exe`, and the contents of your setup.py.

Answer (score 0):

Py2exe might not handle some of the dependencies out of the box. Check this advice from the py2exe tutorial:

[Dealing With ImportError](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/DealingWithImportError)